# is it possible to dynamically include scripts via .gwt.xml?

Tags: gwt, deferred-loading

how can i take advantage of GWT's deferred binding mechanism for script resources (e.g. `CSS`, `JavaScript`)?

the `<define-property ... />` and `<set-property ... />` **(** when used in conjunction with `<when-property-is ... />` **)** does not provide this functionality since they're used for Java types binding.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the  is used for Java types, you can use that paradigm and wrap your css and js in java/gwt classes.  The js will use the native js interface to wrap up the methods and the css can be included in a CssResource/ClientBundle class.  Then just use the gwt.xml file to use whichever one you need for the conditions you have.

Comment: sounds nice, but i decided to take a different approach - loading the required scripts at runtime (on demand). hope i can get this to work...